# Flex programmatically ordering Canvas

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flash-builder

I am wondering if it is possible to set the display order of your canvas' programmatically?

For Example i have

```
<mx:Canvas id="head">
...content...
</mx:Canvas>

<mx:Canvas id="shoulders">
...content...
</mx:Canvas>

<mx:Canvas id="knees">
...content...
</mx:Canvas>

<mx:Canvas id="toes">
...content...
</mx:Canvas>
```

could i set a variable to define the order the canvas' are displayed? so i could have [head, shoulders, toes, knees] for one user and [toes, head, shoulders, knees] for another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the methods [swapChildren](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#swapChildren%28%29) and [swapChildrenAt](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#swapChildrenAt%28%29) to change the Z-order of a component's children.

In MXML, children are created in the order they are displayed, so if you want knees to be above shoulders, you'll have to change the order of your components, like this:

```
<mx:Canvas id="head">
...content...
</mx:Canvas>

<mx:Canvas id="knees">
...content...
</mx:Canvas>

<mx:Canvas id="shoulders">
...content...
</mx:Canvas>

<mx:Canvas id="toes">
...content...
</mx:Canvas>
```

Or you could use the above methods to change the order after the fact.